# Testing a combined Objective-C/Swift application resulting in unresolved identifier?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

As mentioned in the title, this is a small, combined Swift (predominantly) and Objective-C application. In order to allow for the combination, a bridging header was added. Specifically, my issue arises when I attempt to test one of my Swift classes that depends upon the Objective-C class. Consider the following contrived app that reproduces my issue:

**Expression.swift**

```
public class Expression: NSObject {
    public func add(value: String) {
        CustomObj.doSomething()  // CustomObj is my Objective-c class
    }
}
```

**CustomObj.h**

```
@interface CustomObj : NSObject
+ (void) doSomething();
@end
```

**MyApp-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "CustomObj.h"
```

Twiddling with the Target Membership, two scenarios occur.

1. `Expression.swift` belongs to `MyApp` **only**, not `MyAppTests`.

   - The main project compiles fine, but reference errors occur in the tests (ExpressionTest.swift): `Use of undeclared type 'Expression'`.
2. `Expression.swift` belongs to **both** `MyApp` and `MyAppTests`.

   - The project fails to compile, due to an error in `Expression.swift`: `Use of unresolved identifier 'CustomObj'`.

So, it seems I'm somewhat stuck. I've tried various things including adding both the bridging header and CustomObj header into the "Build Phases" -> "Headers Phase", but no luck ... same scenarios from above. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of back and forth, I've come up with a resolution to my issue.

The bridging header was part of the header phases, but I needed to add the bridging header to the "Objective-C Bridging Header" property under my test projects "Build Settings" -> "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" section. This seemed to get rid of any compile errors.